# Is the anchor tag in the html code of the website or is it displayed in the Google serps?

Tags: html, seo, google-search

Trying to put below link in search as highlighted in picture

[image]

I don't have idea how can I add those link. Do we need to make any changes in HTML source of website or need to change something in google webmasters?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register your site with Google's Webmaster Tools package.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

When logged in and registered you will have a section within the left sidebar 'Search Appearance', expand/click this item and then select the sub-section titled as 'Data Highlighter' that should help you with this.

Comment: FYI: Not sure if their info video is available on that page if not logged-in, they also have it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrEJds3QeTw

Comment: After how many time I will get Data Highlighter links on my site search, Do you have any idea?